# Join for a Nested Relationship in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQL Alchemy and having some issues getting the desired results from a join.
I have the following models

```
class QShow(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50))
    starts_on = db.Column(db.Date)
    ends_on = db.Column(db.Date)
    form_id = db.Column(db.String(50))

class Competition(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60))
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('q_show.id'))
    show = db.relationship("QShow", backref=db.backref("showa", uselist=False))

class Start(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rider_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('rider.id'))
    rider = db.relationship("Rider", backref=db.backref("riders", uselist=False))
    competition_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('competition.id'))
    competition = db.relationship("Competition", backref=db.backref("competitiona", uselist=False))
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('q_show.id'))
    show = db.relationship("QShow",  backref=db.backref("shows",uselist=False))

class Rider(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(35))
    starts = db.relationship('Start',backref='riderref',lazy='dynamic')
```

For each show there are multiple competitions, and each competition has multiple starts, a rider requires a start to participate in a competition, and they can have more than one per. All of these are part of a show.

The Competition and Start data is easy to query since they have an FK of show_id. However I am looking to get all the riders in a particular show.

With this query, I am getting all riders, regardless of show. I know I am missing something.

```
rider = Rider.query \
           .join(Start) \
           .join(Competition) \
           .filter(QShow.id == show_id)
```

Can someone help me make sense of this madness?

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried adding QShow to the join, which makes sense, however I still receive riders from all shows.

```
rider = Rider.query \
          .join(Start) \
          .join(Competition) \
          .join(QShow)\
          .filter(QShow.id == show_id)
```

**UPDATE 2**

In thinking about it, I did a workaround that works, however I'd still like to understand what I was doing wrong with the join all the way from Rider -> Show.

```
rider = Rider.query \
           .join(Start) \
           .filter(Start.show_id == show_id)
```

Comment: You didn't `.join` with `QShow` table, why?

Comment: I tried that, with the same result

Comment: Please, post how you tried that, and if possible post relevant code to your query? and I don't see `.all()` at the end of your query?

Comment: If it gives you the same result, it means you have issues with the data in your tables.

Comment: @univerio you are correct! There were 2 incorrect entries that were causing it. Thanks for validating my syntax was correct. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@univerio was correct. The issue was an inconsistency in the database Foreign Keys. Once I fixed that, the join statements worked perfectly.